# Does react-native support react-click-outside?

Tags: react-native

I am porting a react-js project to react-native. I would like to reuse the react-click-outside library. But I consider the following problem when adding it to my dependencies and using `handleClickOutside()` method. The error message is:

The development server returned response error code: 500

> URL:
>   http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false
>
> Body: {"message":"Unable to resolve module react-dom from
>   /Users/xxx/ReactNativeProjects/react_native_prototype/node_modules/react-click-outside/dist/index.js:
>   Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:\n 
>   /Users/xxx/ReactNativeProjects/react_native_prototype/node_modules\n\nThis
>   might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try
>   the following:\n
>
> 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n
> 2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n
> 3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`

I went through all the steps but still I get the same error message when I run the app in Android and/or iOS simulator.

Then I looked into the `/Users/xxx/ReactNativeProjects/react_native_prototype/node_modules/react-click-outside/dist/index.js`file and saw that the library imports something from `react-dom`. But I think react-native doesn't use any DOM? Is that right? So react-click-outside only seems to be compatible with react-js but not with react-native. Am I right? Or did anyone maybe find a simple solution to simulate `handleClickOutside()`behaviour?

My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
(...)
import clickOutside from 'react-click-outside';

const newClass = class TrafficNodeFinder extends React.Component {

    (...)    
    handleClickOutside() {
        this.setState({
            listOfNodes: ds.cloneWithRows([])
        });
    }

    (...) 


}

export default clickOutside(newClass);
```

The error I get now looks like this:

> Can't find variable: document
>
> WrappedTrafficNodeFinder_componentDidMount
>       index.js:17
>
> ReactCompositeComponent.js:353
>
> measureLifeCyclePerf
>       ReactCompositeComponent.js:85
>
> ReactCompositeComponent.js:352
>
> notifyAll
>       CallbackQueue.js:73
>
> close
>       ReactNativeReconcileTransaction.js:36
>
> closeAll
>       Transaction.js:222
>
> perform
>       Transaction.js:163
>
> batchedMountComponentIntoNode
>       ReactNativeMount.js:77
>
> perform
>       Transaction.js:149
>
> batchedUpdates
>       ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:65
>
> batchedUpdates
>       ReactUpdates.js:111
>
> renderComponent
>       ReactNativeMount.js:141
>
> render
>       ReactNative.js:31
>
> renderApplication
>       renderApplication.js:33
>
> run
>       AppRegistry.js:76
>
> runApplication
>       AppRegistry.js:105
>
> __callFunction
>       MessageQueue.js:236
>
> MessageQueue.js:108
>
> guard
>       MessageQueue.js:46
>
> callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       MessageQueue.js:107

I just tried to simulate the behaviour of react-click-outside. I wanted to already surrounded the component which shall react on a click outside of it with View-Elements. But it seems that Views and other react-native UI components don't have any click handler. When I surround my View with a TouchableHighlight it is only clickable if I put a padding. Otherwise all children components "consume" the click events of there parents. Maybe I can somehow tell the children in my view hierarchy to pass the click events to there parents?

Answer (score 1):

No, `react-click-outside` relies on `document.addEventListener`, but there is no document in React Native, as there is no underlying DOM.

Comment: OK, thx. And do you now if it is possible to intercept touch events in `react-native`? Maybe like on Android? https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html